# Why does file.read() return '' in python

Tags: python, file, integer

I am making a blockchain, I am storing the latest block in a file named `lb.store`
,but my code to open and read the file returns `''`.

Here is the Error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ShayanNew\Documents\programming\Python\Blockchain\Node\node.py", line 48, in <module>
    recieve_request()
  File "C:\Users\ShayanNew\Documents\programming\Python\Blockchain\Node\node.py", line 39, in recieve_request
    add_block(data)
  File "C:\Users\ShayanNew\Documents\programming\Python\Blockchain\Node\node.py", line 7, in add_block
    new_block_number = int(lblock_number) + 1
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Here is the full code that caused this:

```
lblock_numberf = open("lb.store","a+")
    lblock_number = lblock_numberf.read()
    lblock_numberf.close()
    new_block_number = int(lblock_number) + 1
```

Comment: then remove the space? `text.replace(' ','')`

Comment: that means your at the end of the file and there is nothing more to read (or the file was empty in the first place)

Comment: the file currently has one character '0'

Comment: Why are you opening it in `a+` mode?

Comment: @shayanbahrainy well, then you were at the EOF when you tried to `.read` from it. Which makes sense with your updated code, since you opened it in append mode, so the cursor is at the EOF (so you can append with writes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that the file you're trying to read is either empty or the end of the string appears to be <"">. Play around the values to debug the problem

Answer (score 0):

Opening in A+ mode means the cursor is at the end of the file, ready to append. Fix this by opening in read mode; the default.

```
lblock_numberf = open("lb.store")
lblock_number = lblock_numberf.read()
lblock_numberf.close()
new_block_number = int(lblock_number) + 1
```